# Cloning windows 10 to SSD NVMe without a reader

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive, clone

I just bought a new SSD NVMe and I want to clone my existing windows 10 with all the softwares installed and configurations to the new SSD. The problem is that I don't have an SSD reader to connect it to my laptop and do the cloning. But I do have an external HDD drive and I was wondering if it's possible to clone my windows to this drive and then install the new SSD in my laptop and clone the windows from the HDD drive to the newly installed SSD.

Thank you.

Comment: It should work.

Comment: Better to make an image of the current drive, then put in new nvme and apply the image. I Use Macrium Reflect free for this. Once MRF is installed make the image of the drive, then the usb rescue media, this is what you will boot from to apply the image you made using MRF..

Comment: Correct, a bit for bit copy.

Comment: You can also use the Windows 7 backup and restore tool (yes, I ***know*** you are in windows 10).  It's free, already installed, and works VERY well.  "Control Panel\System and Security\Backup and Restore (Windows 7)".  I used it to do the EXACT same process.  You will need a Windows 10 boot USB or recovery boot to go with it.

Comment: "Better to make an image of the current drive, then put in new nvme and apply the image. I Use Macrium Reflect free for this." I have used this method more than once when installing SSDs. Macrium Reflect is ideal for this.